# How to get an Air application to process keyboard input

Tags: flash, air, flex4

I am attempting to run an Adobe Air application that I created in Flex Builder 4.6. This application, for various reasons, needs to be able to process keyboard events.

My attempt is in the following form:

```
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                   xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                   xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
                   keyDown="keyPressed(event)">
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        private var connection:NetConnection;

        public function keyPressed(event:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            Alert.show("Pressed: "+event.keyCode,"key Event");
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
 ... Other Stuff...
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

This does not appear to work. I click on the resulting window and press keys. Nothing happens.

Have I found a bug in the Air window, or is there something else I need to do in order to make my application properly process keyboard input?

Someone please advise...

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the event listener?

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, reportKeyDown);

Comment: Yes, I did. There was such a call in the startup function. It does not work at all.